# Good interface for reverting effect of function

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my job, we often write functions that do some calculation and write the result to a database. Sometimes mistakes are made and wrong stuff ends up being saved, therefore we also want to supply an interface to clean up after the function. This is an attempt of solving that problem.

```
from functools import wraps

def revert(func):
    if not hasattr(func,'_revert'):
        raise NotImplementedError(func.__name__ + " does not have a revert registered")

    @wraps(func._revert)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        return func._revert(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper

def register_revert(revert):
    def revert_added(func):
        func._revert = revert

        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
            return func(*args,**kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return revert_added

def _is_it_a_str(maybe_str):
    if not isinstance(maybe_str,str):
         raise ValueError("I need a string")

def _revert_stuff(a_str):
    _is_it_a_str(a_str)
    print('revert stuff with ' + a_str)

@register_revert(_revert_stuff)
def do_stuff(a_str):
    _is_it_a_str(a_str)
    print('doing stuff with ' + a_str)


do_stuff('something')
# Oops:
revert(do_stuff)('something')
```

The idea is to write your function doing your job - do_something in this case. And then when you are ready to take it to the next level, you write its revert, register it and you are done.

I like that

- the solution does not require changing anything in the main functionality.
- you can use the same identical interface for many functions
- the syntax reads relatively intuitively

I think it is inconvenient that

- I need to maintain two identical interfaces - the one on do_stuff and _revert_stuff needs to be identical (or at least _revert_stuff needs to work getting the one from do_stuff).
- sometimes I want to type-check the arguments which I then also have to repeat (exemplified here with _is_it_a_str). I thought about moving that to another decorator, but I'm afraid it gets too confusing.

Edit: We use the newest stable version of Python

p.s. My first question tried my best. Critique welcome!

Comment: python 3.x or 2.x? more specific version would also be helpful

Comment: Why are you doing something and then reverting it. In your example, you could do the type check or string validation before you run `do_stuff` by decorating the `do_stuff` function and checking its inputs, for example with pydantic.

Comment: @Tweakimp The function gets called in error and now we need to clean up. Type checking: Yea I guess another decorator is the correct solution

Comment: I'd like to hear more about how you would use this. I'm thinking of data manipulation, where functions may or may not be combined. In that scenario, you would have to revert all the changes you made, in reverse order, up to the change you want reverted. Then you could re-apply the non-reverted ones. It still leaves open the possibility of non-reversible operations (modulus, regexp), and so you would need a way to mark those.

Comment: @aghast, How the reversion is done is left to the function registered, right? But yea, those are valid issues. Sometimes the ordering matters but that is somewhat logical if it mattered when calling the functions in the first place. Some stuff isn't reversible sure, but the solution definitely does not claim to be able to revert anything. You just don't register a revert.

The specific use case is a lot of functions that do a calculation and saves the result to a database - i updated the description slightly.

Answer (score 3):

```py
def revert(func):
    @wraps(func._revert)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        return func._revert(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

You are returning a wrapper, which takes arguments, calls a function, and returns results...

I'm pretty sure that is just a long way of writing:

```py
def revert(func):
    return func._revert
```

This begs the question: why store the revert function as `func._revert`, when you could store it as `func.revert`?  Then instead of:

```
revert(do_stuff)('something')
```

you could write:

```
do_stuff.revert('something')
```

which is one character shorter.  Even better: autocomplete can tell you whether there is a `.revert` member for `do_stuff`, which is not possible using `revert(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any complaints about your code itself, so I'll bring up an alternate approach. You mentioned being annoyed at having to duplicate things like typechecking, and I also notice that it's possible to call `revert(do_stuff)("b")` without having ever called `do_stuff("b")` in the first place. Maybe that's desirable, but I feel like it probably isn't.

One way to tackle both those things would be to bind the function's arguments to some undo object, and only make the revert function accessible that way. This way, an undo is guaranteed to undo an action that has been done, with the same arguments (meaning they shouldn't need to be typechecked a second time).

Now, this has some disadvantages but it might be worth considering an approach like

```
class UndoableAction:
    def __init__(self, revert_func, args, kwargs):
        self._revert_func = revert_stuff
        self._args = args
        self._kwargs = kwargs
        self._has_been_undone = False

    def undo(self):
        if self._has_been_undone:
            raise RuntimeError("Could not undo: Action has already been undone")
        else:
            result = self._revert_func(*(self._args), **(self._kwargs))
            self._has_been_undone = True
            return result


def register_revert(revert_func):
    def bind(original_func):
        def bound_func(*args, **kwargs):
            result = original_func(*args, **kwargs)

            return (result, UndoableAction(revert_func, args, kwargs))

        return bound_func
    
    return bind


def _revert_stuff(a_str):
    # Since this should only be called as some_action.undo()
    # we can assume do_stuff() has already typechecked the argument
    # So we don't do it ourselves
    print('revert stuff with ' + a_str)


@register_revert(revert_stuff)
def do_stuff(a_str):
    if not isinstance(a_str, str):
        raise ValueError("I need a string")

    print('do stuff with ' + a_str)


_, stuff = do_stuff('something')
# Oh no!
stuff.undo()
```

The syntax remains fairly intuitive, and the same interface still works for many functions. Duplication is down, and while the two functions still need to be kept in sync to a degree, the undo function doesn't end up exposing much of an interface at all. And there is also no need to worry about trying to undo an operation that hasn't actually been done. But of course, it *does* look different to callers of the main functionality. It also might make it harder to undo an action if the action was initially done in an entirely different part of the program. If you don't have the undo object, you can't easily do something like `revert(create_user)(database.get_a_username())` for example -- but that might not be a major issue, assuming the same code is generally responsible for doing a thing and undoing it (which it sounds like).

It's a tradeoff. Might be worth thinking about, depending on your use case.

Comment: Nice answer (+1).  You might want to ensure `*args` and `**kwargs` are immutable, so they actually contain the same content during the `.undo()`.  Ok, easier said than done.  Maybe try `hash((*args, *kwargs.values()))`: if you get `TypeError: unhashable type: '...'`, then mutable arguments (lists, dictionaries, ...) are being passed to the undoable function.  Of course, just because they are mutable doesn't mean they have mutated ...